# PUT method HTTP Status 400 in Spring MVC - AngularJS

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to update the Company object, as you can see in company.js below.
When I try to call the put method from **company.js**, it gives me the **400 Status error** and the execution does not enter in the put method in **CompanyController.java**. Company object is also available in $scope.
While executing the final URL in **company.js** is:
http://localhost:8080/Jobkreisel/protected/company/50
but it does not even enter in the update method in **CompanyController.java**, just move to the error block in **$http.put(url, $scope.company, config)** method.

**company.js**

```
  $scope.updateCompany = function (updateCompanyForm) {
        if (!updateCompanyForm.$valid) {
            $scope.displayValidationError = true;
            return;
        }
        $scope.lastAction = 'update';
        var url = '/Jobkreisel/protected/company/' + $scope.company.companyID;


        var config = {};

        alert("Company scope "+$scope.company.companyID);
        alert("Company config "+config);

        $http.put(url, $scope.company, config)
            .success(function (data) {

                alert('In update success');
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                console.debug(data);
                alert('data:' + data);
                alert('status: ' + status); 

                alert('update error');
            });
    };
```

**CompanyController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/protected/company")
public class CompanyController extends UserBaseController {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyService companyService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{companyID}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(@PathVariable("companyID") int companyId,
                                    @RequestBody Company company,                                    
                                    Locale locale) {
        if (companyId != company.getCompanyID()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Bad Request", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        companyService.save(company);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Please tell me why its not executing the success block.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd ">

    <!-- Spring servlet that will handle the requests-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring basic configurations -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/spring.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Enconding helper filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Encoding utility -->
    <jsp-config>
        <jsp-property-group>
            <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
            <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
            <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
        </jsp-property-group>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

**Network LOG:**

> Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080 Request
>   URL:http://localhost:8080/Jobkreisel/protected/company/50  Request
>   Method:PUT  Status Code:400 Bad Request  Request Headersview source 
>   Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*  Accept-Encoding:gzip,
>   deflate, sdch  Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8  Connection:keep-alive 
>   Content-Length:175  Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8 
>   Cookie:JSESSIONID=1w425u610rioe  Host:localhost:8080 
>   Origin:http://localhost:8080
>   Referer:http://localhost:8080/Jobkreisel/protected/company 
>   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36  Request
>   Payload view source
>
> {companyID: "50", name: "Agrident GmbH", website:
>   "http://www.agrident.com/", twitter: "",…}  ausbildungvideourl: ""
>   companyID: "50" employee: "" facebook: "" name: "Agrident GmbH"
>   studiumvideourl: "" twitter: "" video: ""  website:
>   "http://www.agrident.com/"  Response Headers view source 
>   Content-Length:0 Pragma:no-cache Server:Jetty(6.1.21)

Comment: Hi, is your servlet actually mapped on `/Jobkreisel/*` in your `web.xml` file?

Comment: Hi, question updated, you can check the web.xml file.

Comment: Can you look at a JS debugger (specifically the "net" or "network" tab) and see what the request looks like that Angular is attempting to send?

Comment: Also... you don't need to add the "context-param" if you are telling DispatcherServlet where your spring.xml file is... you only need to do this if you are using multiple DIFFERENT spring context files.

Comment: Check the network Log.

Comment: Like @blint suggested... you don't have anywhere in your web.xml (or your controller) that handles "/Jobkreisel"

Answer (score 0):

The `web.xml` is incomplete: indeed you need a servlet mapping of `/Jobkreisel/*` to your controllers.

Just replace the `<url-pattern>` tag of your spring dispatcher as follows:

```
<!-- Spring servlet that will handle the requests-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    ...
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Jobkreisel/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You also could change the url called from your angular app if the mapping of the dispatcher is correct:

```
    var url = '/protected/company/' + $scope.company.companyID;
```

Comment: I am using jetty, the URL created  http://localhost:8080/Jobkreisel , as u suggested I added this URL pattern, but now its showing 404 error on all pages. no page is working. Please suggest further.